# Can not echo data from MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

Hello! The data in table is like that, and I cannot echo these entries individually. I want to show this data in HTML table like for example, Subject: Math, Correct: 34, Wrong: 6.

I am new in php, please help me with this case.

Comment: Please post code / json in text and not image.

Answer (score 1):

The data in the table seems to be in JSON format. You can convert it to a PHP object using `json_decode()` then print that object using `print_r()`.

When put all together, you get

```
echo print_r(json_decode($data), true);
```

Note, I have to edit this response back to what it is now because @fenil-shah had changed it some something else that was not suitable. Please send your own response instead of making others say what they didn't intend to.

@fenil-shah, my answer was written the way it was on purpose. Here are the explanations:

1. In general, if you want to stay in control of the result of the print_r() function, you need to return its result as a string. That's why I have passed true as second parameter for the print_r() function. You wouldn't using print_r() without returning its result as a string in a middle of another script because it will output some text in an uncontrolled manner that can break an add. Once you have the return string, you can send it to a log file or do whatever you want with it.
2. json_decode works beautifully without passing it a true as second parameter. The OP's example is showing a object. You edit was purposely changing the decoded object to an array with associative array. Why?
3. You have removed the space after the comma which you had moved in from the print_r() to the json_decode() to make it look like `json_decode($data,true)`. You need to know that the space was there for two reasons: Readability and Compliance with the PSR-2 standard (read more about that PHP coding standard at https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#46-method-and-function-calls).

Answer (score 0):

There are `echo ""`,`print_r()` and `print()` function available in php to print data.If query is returning array then use `print_r()` function but if query is not returning anything or invalid fetch method in php then data is not getting display by any of these functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want as a output.
  You can decode the JSON received from database using `json_decode()` function and get your result transformed in associative array.
Later on passing the array in `foreach()` loop will do your work accordingly

```
 <?php
    $result = '{
      "30": {
      "subject_id":343,
      "correct_answers":34,
      "wrong _answers":61,
      "not_answered":0,
      "time_spent":3801,
      "time_to_spend":3680,
      "time_spent_correct_ answers":3286,
      "time_spent_wrong_answers":515 
      },
      "52": {
        "subject_id":52,
        "correct_answers":7,
        "wrong_answers":3,
        "not_answered":0,
        "time_spent":883 ,
        "time_to_spend":94343,
        "time_spent_correct_ans wers":352,
        "time_spent wrong_answers":441
      },
      "53": {
        "subject_id":53,
        "correct_answers":3,
        "wrong_answers":7,
        "not_answered":43,
        "time_spent":584 ,
        "time_to_spend":900,
        "time_spent_correct_ans wers":154,
        "time_spent wrong_answers":430
      }
    }';
    $json_decoded_data = json_decode($result,true);
    ?>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>subject_id</th>
                <th>correct_answers</th>
                <th>wrong_answers</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            foreach($json_decoded_data as $row){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row['subject_id']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['correct_answers']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['correct_answers']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
</table>
```